# How to unpack byte into vec3?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need axes aligned normals so i would like to safe memory and send it as byte instead of alpha channel with position. Buffer object is made from 4 bytes: `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLubyte), (void*)0);` Encoding should look like this.

```
//byte in buffer object | unpacked vector
x+ 0010 1011 == vec3( 1,  0,  0)
x- 0010 1001 == vec3(-1,  0,  0)
y+ 0010 1110
y- 0010 0110
z+ 0011 1010
z- 0001 1010

//Lets take vec3(-1, 0, 1) encoded velue looks like 0011 1001
//               ,(operation) -> (result),
//Z = >>4 -> 0000 0011, &mask -> 0000 0011, -2 -> 0000 0001
//Y = >>2 -> 0000 1110, &mask -> 0000 0010, -2 -> 0000 0000
//X = >>0 -> 0011 1001, &mask -> 0000 0001, -2 -> 1111 1111
```

I checked encoding in gDEBuggerGL and it is right. The problem comes in vertex shader since unpacking is quite clumsy.

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex_position;
//...
int byte = int(vertex_position.w);

const int mask = 0x00000003; 
vec3 v_normal;
v_normal.x = float(((byte >> 0) & mask) - 2);
v_normal.y = float(((byte >> 2) & mask) - 2);
v_normal.z = float(((byte >> 4) & mask) - 2);
```

**Firstly:** Is there better way how to accomplish this?

**Secondly:** I rendered this normal vector into float texture and found that some values are wrong. Many of them are not {1, 0, -1} but close to this. Well I don't think this code should introduce any precision errors so why is this happening?

[image: Normals in float texture]

**Update:**
The precision error is introduced in transition from vertex shader to fragment shader and can be solved by adding `flat` keyword. (thanks Chris Dodd)

Comment: `8 * sizeof(GLubyte)` looks a little suspect?

Comment: Sorry, I should have changed it. There are two buffers both with 4*byte. But the other one doesn't relate to this question.

Comment: You do realize that between the vertex shader and fragment shader, your `v_normal` will be interpolated unless you take steps to do otherwise...

Comment: No, i have forgotten about it. Thanks for pointing that out. ```flat``` keyword solved precision errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Lets take vec3(-1, 0, 1) encoded velue looks like 0011 1001    
//X = >> 0 -> 0011 1001, &mask -> 0000 0001, -2 -> ffff ffff
```

`0xFFFFFF` is not `-1` because you are using a `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, and therefore this isn't a 2's complement representation.

Comment: This is still wrong, because you're casting it to an `int` first. I'll keep thinking... ;p

Comment: Actually, could you try using `GL_BYTE`? This uses 2's complement representation, and that's consistent with your logic.

Comment: Nothing has changed. ```Vertex_position.w``` is actually float, since it come in vec4 because gpu don't have byte vector or byte alone. But then it's casted into integer and the rest of magic is done over int that has 2's complement representation.

Comment: What if you isolate the sign bit and multiply it by minus one, then multiply that by the value of the corresponding co-ordinate bit? It's a far less efficient solution, but it should be able to at least provide you with consistent data and rule out other possibilities.

Comment: The precision problem is spread across all dimensions and both signs only zero value is not affected. It's not problem specific to negative transition. I just can't provide one sample picture with both positive and negative normals in all dimensions.

Comment: I mean check that a separate implementation altogether will give the correct results, i.e. `(float((X >> 1) & 0x01) * -1)*(float((X >> 0) & 0x01))`.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find out the answer to this problem?

Comment: This answer has two parts. The first part is already solved by Chris and i updated question to include solution. The second part is just how to make it not so clumsy.